# Can't access Rancher UI after deploying it on K3S via helm

Tags: kubernetes, helm, k3s, rancher

I deployed Rancher on K3S cluster using steps documented in below guide: https://ranchermanager.docs.rancher.com/getting-started/quick-start-guides/deploy-rancher-manager/helm-cli

The pod is working fine but I absolutely can't access Rancher UI on URL I provided.

```
helm install rancher rancher-latest/rancher   --namespace cattle-system   --set hostname=192.168.68.115.local   --set replicas=1   --set bootstrapPassword=
NAME: rancher
LAST DEPLOYED: Sat Oct  7 17:53:15 2023
NAMESPACE: cattle-system
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
NOTES:
Rancher Server has been installed.
echo https://192.168.68.115.local/dashboard/?setup=$(kubectl get secret --namespace cattle-system bootstrap-secret -o go-template='{{.data.bootstrapPassword|base64decode}}')

https://192.168.68.115.local/dashboard/?setup=asdasdasd
```

When I try to access it, there's nothing coming up.

There seems to be no external IP assigned to the pod (obviously), but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to get to the UI. Edit my /etc/resolv.conf onthe node?